# Existe tal cosa como JDK SE y JDK EE?

Tags: java, eclipse, java-ee, sdk

Sabemos que java esta "dividido" en JAVA SE y JAVA EE.

Cuando vas a descargar eclipse puedes ver las opciones de descargas:

- ECLIPSE SE
- ECLIPSE EE
- ETC...

**Mi pregunta es**

Existe tal cosa como JDK SE y JDK EE,? es decir, es que acaso yo se que estoy trabajando con JAVA EE si descargo un IDE EE?

**por ejemplo** ECLIPSE EE?. es decir, cuando vas a descargar el JDK, solo aparece el JDK SE.

Es que el JDK SE sirve para JAVA SE y JAVA EE?

Comment: Arrancó mal la pregunta con el "sabemos". :) Bienvenido y espero que las respuestas resuelvan tu inquietud.

Answer (score 5):

Creo que estás haciendo muchas preguntas en una por falta de investigación, pero trataré de responder la más importante esperando que con ello queden respondidas las demás.

Efectivamente existe oficialmente por parte de Oracle un SDK para Java EE, su nombre es **Java EE Platform SDK**, existe adicionalmente otro SDK para depurarlo, el **Java EE Web Profile SDK** ambos descargables [desde la página oficial](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javaee-8-sdk-downloads.html).

Como dice en la [guía de instalación](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/ee8-install-guide.html), las distribuciones de Java EE 8 SDK requieren JDK 8 Update 144 o superior.

¿Sigue siendo confuso? Bueno, tal vez se deba a que no sabes la diferencia entre un SDK y un JDK.

El JDK es un SDK para el lenguaje Java. Java EE es parte del lenguaje Java, y su SDK es un conjunto adicional de herramientas para permitirte el desarrollo de programas empresariales en Java.

En su especificación original el [JSR 58](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=58) como se mostró la público en 2001, Java EE comprendía las siguientes mejoras a Java SE:

- Enterprise JavaBeans ( [ejb](/questions/tagged/ejb) )
- Java Server Pages ( [jsp](/questions/tagged/jsp) )
- [servlets](/questions/tagged/servlets)
- Java Message Service ( [jms](/questions/tagged/jms) )

Adicionalmente te recomiendo darle una leida a las etiquetas [jdk](/questions/tagged/jdk), [java-ee](/questions/tagged/java-ee).

Para usuarios un poco más leídos:

A partir de [java-9](/questions/tagged/java-9), algunos de los elementos más pesados cuya funcionalidad realmente pertenecía a Java EE se extrajeron del JDK mediante el módulo [java.se.ee](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java.se.ee-summary.html) y dicho módulo desaparece a partir de [java-11](/questions/tagged/java-11), requiriendo agregar manualmente cada dependencia que originalmente estaba contenida en el módulo `java.se.ee`, como es el caso de [jaxb](/questions/tagged/jaxb).

#### ¿Y tras toda esa teoría que hay que hacer en el eclipse para desarrollar Java EE?

Bueno, realmente esos APIs están ya implementados en los servidores de aplicaciones, así que generalmente basta con crear un proyecto de tipo JavaEE ( si nuestro proyecto se construye como siempre con [ant](/questions/tagged/ant) ) para que agregue al classpath las dependencias de un core de un servidor empresarial que tengamos instalado como puede ser: [tomcat](/questions/tagged/tomcat), [glassfish](/questions/tagged/glassfish), [websphere](/questions/tagged/websphere), [wildfly](/questions/tagged/wildfly), [payara](/questions/tagged/payara), [weblogic](/questions/tagged/weblogic), [tomee](/questions/tagged/tomee), etc; o en su defecto agregar las dependencias en un sistema de construcción como lo puede ser: [maven](/questions/tagged/maven), [gradle](/questions/tagged/gradle), leningen (creo que así se llama), [bazel](/questions/tagged/bazel), [ivy](/questions/tagged/ivy), etc

¿Y si me da flojera configurar mi eclipse?

No te preocupes, ya hay una distribución de eclipse que trae todos los plugins para que puedas desarrollar Java EE, y se llama [Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java Developers](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/2020-09/r/eclipse-ide-enterprise-java-developers), básicamente es un eclipse normal pero trae los sigiuentes plugins:

- Data Tools Platform
- Git integration for Eclipse
- Eclipse Java Development Tools
- Eclipse Java EE Developer Tools
- Maven Integration for Eclipse
- Mylyn Task List
- Eclipse Plug-in Development Environment

Answer (score 2):

Básicamente `JavaSE` es la implementación base para la construcción de programas en lenguaje Java, pero `JavaEE` es más una especificación de tecnologías que se consideran de carácter empresarial como son el manejo de `cluster`, `mensajeria JMS`, `EJB`, etc. Estas tecnologías no están dentro de la versión JavaSE y se necesita un servidor de aplicaciones que las implemente, por Ejemplo: Websphere de IBM, Weblogic de Oracle, Wilfly de RedHat, Glassfish. Cada uno de estos servidores implemente su propia implementación de JavaEE según la especificación JavaEE, por eso el servidor `Tomcat` no se considera un servidor `JavaEE` porque solo implementa `Servlet` para la tecnología web y no el total de la especificación,  así que algunas librerías varían entre servidores o incluso su configuración, además de tener que instalar el plugin del servidor espesifico en caso no tenerlo disponible, en `EclipseEE` lo que tienes es una serie de plugins preinstalados que te permitirán interactuar con los servidores y crear proyectos más avanzados como proyectos web, mientras que en `EclipseSE` solo podrás crear proyectos java de consola o escritorio, esto no quiere decir que en `EclipseSE` no se puedan crear proyectos mas avanzados sino que debes instalar uno a uno los plugins faltantes.